# Standalone Braid server - ERROR: failed to parse or resolve type => unable to register flow

Tags: corda

I am trying to connect a standalone Braid server to local nodes started by deployNodes gradle task (Corda 4.3, Braid 4.1.2). Our Cordapp features Corda Accounts.

Now at the startup of braid-server (in IntelliJ, with the command line arguments `localhost:10006 usernm passwd 10200 3 ".../PartyA/cordapps"`) braid successfully extracts APIs for some flows, while for others I get errors like this one:

```
08:34:24.204 [braid-startup-threadpool-0] ERROR io.bluebank.braid.core.synth.SyntheticModelConverter - failed to parse or resolve type: class generated.com.r3.corda.lib.accounts.workflows.flows.RequestKeyForAccountPayload
08:34:24.205 [braid-startup-threadpool-0] WARN  io.bluebank.braid.corda.server.BraidCordaStandaloneServer - unable to register flow:com.r3.corda.lib.accounts.workflows.flows.RequestKeyForAccount
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to convert actual type: class generated.com.r3.corda.lib.accounts.workflows.flows.RequestKeyForAccountPayload
    at io.bluebank.braid.corda.rest.docs.v3.ModelContextV3.addType(ModelContextV3.kt:72) ~[classes/:?]
    at io.bluebank.braid.corda.rest.docs.v3.EndPointV3.resolveTypes$braid_corda(EndPointV3.kt:113) ~[classes/:?]
    at io.bluebank.braid.corda.rest.docs.v3.EndPointV3$Companion.create(EndPointV3.kt:71) ~[classes/:?]
    at io.bluebank.braid.corda.rest.docs.v3.DocsHandlerV3.add(DocsHandlerV3.kt:145) ~[classes/:?]
    at io.bluebank.braid.corda.rest.RestMounter.bind(RestMounter.kt:280) ~[classes/:?]
    at io.bluebank.braid.corda.rest.RestMounter.postFuture(RestMounter.kt:247) ~[classes/:?]
    at io.bluebank.braid.corda.server.BraidCordaStandaloneServer.addFlow(BraidCordaStandaloneServer.kt:271) ~[classes/:?]
    at io.bluebank.braid.corda.server.BraidCordaStandaloneServer.access$addFlow(BraidCordaStandaloneServer.kt:46) ~[classes/:?]
    at io.bluebank.braid.corda.server.BraidCordaStandaloneServer$createRestConfig$1$2$3.invoke(BraidCordaStandaloneServer.kt:254) ~[classes/:?]
    at io.bluebank.braid.corda.server.BraidCordaStandaloneServer$createRestConfig$1$2$3.invoke(BraidCordaStandaloneServer.kt:46) ~[classes/:?]
    at io.bluebank.braid.corda.rest.RestMounter.group(RestMounter.kt:165) ~[classes/:?]
    at io.bluebank.braid.corda.server.BraidCordaStandaloneServer$createRestConfig$1$2.invoke(BraidCordaStandaloneServer.kt:248) ~[classes/:?]
    at io.bluebank.braid.corda.server.BraidCordaStandaloneServer$createRestConfig$1$2.invoke(BraidCordaStandaloneServer.kt:46) ~[classes/:?]
    at io.bluebank.braid.corda.rest.RestMounter.protected(RestMounter.kt:197) ~[classes/:?]
    at io.bluebank.braid.corda.server.BraidCordaStandaloneServer$createRestConfig$1.invoke(BraidCordaStandaloneServer.kt:238) ~[classes/:?]
    at io.bluebank.braid.corda.server.BraidCordaStandaloneServer$createRestConfig$1.invoke(BraidCordaStandaloneServer.kt:46) ~[classes/:?]
    at io.bluebank.braid.corda.rest.RestConfig$withPaths$1.invoke(RestConfig.kt:67) ~[classes/:?]
    at io.bluebank.braid.corda.rest.RestConfig$withPaths$1.invoke(RestConfig.kt:23) ~[classes/:?]
    at io.bluebank.braid.corda.rest.RestMounter.mount(RestMounter.kt:99) ~[classes/:?]
    at io.bluebank.braid.corda.rest.RestMounter.<init>(RestMounter.kt:91) ~[classes/:?]
    at io.bluebank.braid.corda.rest.RestMounter$Companion.mount(RestMounter.kt:50) ~[classes/:?]
    at io.bluebank.braid.corda.BraidVerticle.setupRouter(BraidVerticle.kt:120) ~[classes/:?]
    at io.bluebank.braid.corda.BraidVerticle.access$setupRouter(BraidVerticle.kt:35) ~[classes/:?]
    at io.bluebank.braid.corda.BraidVerticle$start$2.handle(BraidVerticle.kt:70) ~[classes/:?]
    at io.bluebank.braid.corda.BraidVerticle$start$2.handle(BraidVerticle.kt:35) ~[classes/:?]
    at io.vertx.core.impl.ContextImpl.lambda$executeBlocking$2(ContextImpl.java:272) ~[vertx-core-3.7.1.jar:3.7.1]
    at io.vertx.core.impl.TaskQueue.run(TaskQueue.java:76) ~[vertx-core-3.7.1.jar:3.7.1]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [?:1.8.0_171]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [?:1.8.0_171]
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30) [netty-common-4.1.24.Final.jar:4.1.24.Final]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [?:1.8.0_171]
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Lcom/r3/corda/lib/accounts/contracts/states/AccountInfo;
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_171]
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredFields(Class.java:2583) ~[?:1.8.0_171]
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields(Class.java:1916) ~[?:1.8.0_171]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.util.ClassUtil.getDeclaredFields(ClassUtil.java:1078) ~[jackson-databind-2.9.7.jar:2.9.7]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.introspect.AnnotatedFieldCollector._findFields(AnnotatedFieldCollector.java:66) ~[jackson-databind-2.9.7.jar:2.9.7]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.introspect.AnnotatedFieldCollector.collect(AnnotatedFieldCollector.java:41) ~[jackson-databind-2.9.7.jar:2.9.7]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.introspect.AnnotatedFieldCollector.collectFields(AnnotatedFieldCollector.java:36) ~[jackson-databind-2.9.7.jar:2.9.7]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.introspect.AnnotatedClass._fields(AnnotatedClass.java:349) ~[jackson-databind-2.9.7.jar:2.9.7]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.introspect.AnnotatedClass.fields(AnnotatedClass.java:321) ~[jackson-databind-2.9.7.jar:2.9.7]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.introspect.POJOPropertiesCollector._addFields(POJOPropertiesCollector.java:379) ~[jackson-databind-2.9.7.jar:2.9.7]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.introspect.POJOPropertiesCollector.collectAll(POJOPropertiesCollector.java:308) ~[jackson-databind-2.9.7.jar:2.9.7]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.introspect.POJOPropertiesCollector.getPropertyMap(POJOPropertiesCollector.java:287) ~[jackson-databind-2.9.7.jar:2.9.7]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.introspect.POJOPropertiesCollector.getProperties(POJOPropertiesCollector.java:170) ~[jackson-databind-2.9.7.jar:2.9.7]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.introspect.BasicBeanDescription._properties(BasicBeanDescription.java:164) ~[jackson-databind-2.9.7.jar:2.9.7]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.introspect.BasicBeanDescription.findProperties(BasicBeanDescription.java:239) ~[jackson-databind-2.9.7.jar:2.9.7]
    at io.bluebank.braid.core.synth.SyntheticModelConverter.resolveSchema(SyntheticModelConverter.kt:189) ~[classes/:?]
    at io.bluebank.braid.core.synth.SyntheticModelConverter.getOrCreateModel(SyntheticModelConverter.kt:157) ~[classes/:?]
    at io.bluebank.braid.core.synth.SyntheticModelConverter.resolve(SyntheticModelConverter.kt:104) ~[classes/:?]
    at io.swagger.v3.core.converter.ModelConverterContextImpl.resolve(ModelConverterContextImpl.java:90) ~[swagger-core-2.0.9.jar:2.0.9]
    at io.swagger.v3.core.converter.ModelConverters.resolveAsResolvedSchema(ModelConverters.java:112) ~[swagger-core-2.0.9.jar:2.0.9]
    at io.bluebank.braid.corda.rest.docs.v3.ModelContextV3.createSwaggerModels(ModelContextV3.kt:116) ~[classes/:?]
    at io.bluebank.braid.corda.rest.docs.v3.ModelContextV3.addType(ModelContextV3.kt:62) ~[classes/:?]
    ... 30 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.r3.corda.lib.accounts.contracts.states.AccountInfo
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381) ~[?:1.8.0_171]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424) ~[?:1.8.0_171]
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:349) ~[?:1.8.0_171]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357) ~[?:1.8.0_171]
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_171]
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredFields(Class.java:2583) ~[?:1.8.0_171]
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields(Class.java:1916) ~[?:1.8.0_171]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.util.ClassUtil.getDeclaredFields(ClassUtil.java:1078) ~[jackson-databind-2.9.7.jar:2.9.7]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.introspect.AnnotatedFieldCollector._findFields(AnnotatedFieldCollector.java:66) ~[jackson-databind-2.9.7.jar:2.9.7]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.introspect.AnnotatedFieldCollector.collect(AnnotatedFieldCollector.java:41) ~[jackson-databind-2.9.7.jar:2.9.7]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.introspect.AnnotatedFieldCollector.collectFields(AnnotatedFieldCollector.java:36) ~[jackson-databind-2.9.7.jar:2.9.7]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.introspect.AnnotatedClass._fields(AnnotatedClass.java:349) ~[jackson-databind-2.9.7.jar:2.9.7]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.introspect.AnnotatedClass.fields(AnnotatedClass.java:321) ~[jackson-databind-2.9.7.jar:2.9.7]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.introspect.POJOPropertiesCollector._addFields(POJOPropertiesCollector.java:379) ~[jackson-databind-2.9.7.jar:2.9.7]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.introspect.POJOPropertiesCollector.collectAll(POJOPropertiesCollector.java:308) ~[jackson-databind-2.9.7.jar:2.9.7]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.introspect.POJOPropertiesCollector.getPropertyMap(POJOPropertiesCollector.java:287) ~[jackson-databind-2.9.7.jar:2.9.7]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.introspect.POJOPropertiesCollector.getProperties(POJOPropertiesCollector.java:170) ~[jackson-databind-2.9.7.jar:2.9.7]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.introspect.BasicBeanDescription._properties(BasicBeanDescription.java:164) ~[jackson-databind-2.9.7.jar:2.9.7]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.introspect.BasicBeanDescription.findProperties(BasicBeanDescription.java:239) ~[jackson-databind-2.9.7.jar:2.9.7]
    at io.bluebank.braid.core.synth.SyntheticModelConverter.resolveSchema(SyntheticModelConverter.kt:189) ~[classes/:?]
    at io.bluebank.braid.core.synth.SyntheticModelConverter.getOrCreateModel(SyntheticModelConverter.kt:157) ~[classes/:?]
    at io.bluebank.braid.core.synth.SyntheticModelConverter.resolve(SyntheticModelConverter.kt:104) ~[classes/:?]
    at io.swagger.v3.core.converter.ModelConverterContextImpl.resolve(ModelConverterContextImpl.java:90) ~[swagger-core-2.0.9.jar:2.0.9]
    at io.swagger.v3.core.converter.ModelConverters.resolveAsResolvedSchema(ModelConverters.java:112) ~[swagger-core-2.0.9.jar:2.0.9]
    at io.bluebank.braid.corda.rest.docs.v3.ModelContextV3.createSwaggerModels(ModelContextV3.kt:116) ~[classes/:?]
    at io.bluebank.braid.corda.rest.docs.v3.ModelContextV3.addType(ModelContextV3.kt:62) ~[classes/:?]
    ... 30 more
```

...and other similar ones:

```
08:34:24.216 [braid-startup-threadpool-0] ERROR io.bluebank.braid.core.synth.SyntheticModelConverter - failed to parse or resolve type: class generated.com.r3.corda.lib.accounts.workflows.flows.ShareAccountInfoPayload
08:34:24.216 [braid-startup-threadpool-0] WARN  io.bluebank.braid.corda.server.BraidCordaStandaloneServer - unable to register flow:com.r3.corda.lib.accounts.workflows.flows.ShareAccountInfo
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to convert actual type: class generated.com.r3.corda.lib.accounts.workflows.flows.ShareAccountInfoPayload
[...]
Caused by: java.lang.TypeNotPresentException: Type com.r3.corda.lib.accounts.contracts.states.AccountInfo not present
[...]
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.r3.corda.lib.accounts.contracts.states.AccountInfo
[...]

08:34:24.233 [braid-startup-threadpool-0] ERROR io.bluebank.braid.core.synth.SyntheticModelConverter - failed to parse or resolve type: class generated.com.r3.corda.lib.accounts.workflows.flows.ShareStateWithAccountPayload
08:34:24.233 [braid-startup-threadpool-0] WARN  io.bluebank.braid.corda.server.BraidCordaStandaloneServer - unable to register flow:com.r3.corda.lib.accounts.workflows.flows.ShareStateWithAccount
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to convert actual type: class generated.com.r3.corda.lib.accounts.workflows.flows.ShareStateWithAccountPayload
[...]
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Lcom/r3/corda/lib/accounts/contracts/states/AccountInfo;
[...]
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.r3.corda.lib.accounts.contracts.states.AccountInfo
[...]

08:34:24.433 [braid-startup-threadpool-0] ERROR io.bluebank.braid.core.synth.SyntheticModelConverter - failed to parse or resolve type: class generated.com.mycompany.tokens.flows.IssueTokenPayload
08:34:24.433 [braid-startup-threadpool-0] WARN  io.bluebank.braid.corda.server.BraidCordaStandaloneServer - unable to register flow:com.mycompany.tokens.flows.IssueToken
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to convert actual type: class generated.com.mycompany.tokens.flows.IssueTokenPayload
[...]
Caused by: java.lang.TypeNotPresentException: Type com.mycompany.data.MyCordappData not present
[...]
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mycordapp.data.MyCordappData
[...]
```

...while many other flows are API'zed with no issues.

Now it would seem that the only flows with problems are the ones with Accounts-related classes or our cordapp classes in the constructor.

Don't know what to try. Can't believe you have to limit Flow constructor signature to standard Java or Corda core classes.
Missing annotations / class loading havoc...?

Answer (score 0):

Project Braid is an open source project by Lab577. https://gitlab.com/bluebank/braid

The issue will be reported to Lab577.